Tracking Discord's window location in React
In React, how to track the location of the new Window, if it location is errorUrl, it will close the new window
const newWindow = window.open(
        `https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&scope=bot&permissions=962311146056&guild_id=${guildId}`,
        "_blank",
        "width=900,height=800"
      );
const errorUrl = "https://discord.com/oauth2/error?error=access_denied";

I have using setInterval() but not working

To track the location of a new window in React and close it if it reaches a specific error URL, you can use a combination of an intermediate handler and routing. This allows you to manage the URL redirection logic more effectively, even when Discord performs redirects that involve different domains or URLs with varying parameters.
import React from "react";

function ComponentA() {
  const openNewWindow = () => {
    const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent("http://localhost:3000/new-window-handler");
    const newWin = window.open(
      `http://localhost:3000/new-window-handler?redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`,
      "_blank",
      "width=900,height=800"
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={openNewWindow}>Authorize Discord Bot</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestComponent;

Below component handles URL param checking and redirection:
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

function NewWindowHandler() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const error = urlParams.get('error');

    if (error === 'access_denied') {
      console.log("OAuth Error: Access Denied");
      window.close(); // Close the window if there's an error
    } else {
      // If no error, redirect to Discord
      const clientId = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID';
      const guildId = 'YOUR_GUILD_ID';
      const discordRedirectUri = `https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&scope=bot&permissions=962311146056&guild_id=${guildId}`;

      window.location.href = discordRedirectUri; // Redirect to Discord
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Authorizing...</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NewWindowHandler;

This setup provides a robust way to manage URL-based logic in a new window while leveraging React components and routing to ensure proper OAuth handling with Discord. By checking URL parameters on a page you control, you can effectively handle errors and manage redirects without encountering cross-origin issues.
Note: Don't forget to add NewWindowHandler to Routes as path

I've done like in your instruction but didn't work

Does it not open a new window, or is there no redirect after opening a new window?

it have open the new window and have redirect, but not auto close the window when location have 'error' in it

console.log("OAuth Error: Access Denied");
When your url has error, does it write this text to console ? if it doesn't, you should check the getting params from url.

the location at first is "http://localhost:3000/new-window-handler?redirect_uri=${redirectUri}" and can log everything, after redirect it is "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={clientID}&scope=bot&permissions=962311146056". the logs are from Discord
